# Empty JMenuItems in JMenuBar on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I have a problem creating a JFrame with a JMenuBar. 
I have a MenuBarBuilder class here:

```
public class MenuBuilder extends JMenuBar
{
  private Model model;

  public MenuBuilder(Model model)
  {
    this.model = model;
    buildMenuBar();
  }

  public void buildMenuBar()
  {
    JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu menuEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
    JMenu menuHelp = new JMenu("Help");

    menuHelp.setMnemonic('H');
    menuFile.setMnemonic('F');
    menuEdit.setMnemonic('E');

    JMenuItem menuItemExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    menuItemExit.setAccelerator(model.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0));

    menuItemExit.setAction(new ActionExit(model));

    menuFile.add(menuItemExit);

    add(menuFile);
    add(menuEdit);
    add(menuHelp);
  }
}
```

And the JFrame is created in another class:

```
public MainGUI(boolean loadConfig, String loadConfigDir, Model model)
  {
    try
    {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)
    {
      GlobalVariables.LOGGING_logger.error("Something went wrong while getting the Look and Feel of current Windows Version for Userinterface", e);
    }

    try
    {
      this.model = model;

      frameMain = new JFrame("MainFrame");
      frameMain.setJMenuBar(new MenuBuilder(model));
      frameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
      frameMain.addWindowListener(this);
      frameMain.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      frameMain.pack();
      frameMain.setSize(800, 800);
      frameMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frameMain.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      GlobalVariables.LOGGING_logger.error("Error while seeting up the main GUI.", e);
      MessagesToUser.errorMessageBothFilesIssue(true);
    }
  }
```

After showing the `JFrame`, all MenuItems are empty, but existing and the function (`ActionExit`) is also working correct. Setting the new `JMenuItem` with the following code `menuFile.add(new JMenuItem("Exit"));` is working as expected and the JFrame has the correct `JMenuBar`. Why is this happening???

EDIT:
Here is the ActionExit class which just exits the program:

```
public class ActionExit extends AbstractAction
{
  private Model model;

  public ActionExit(Model model)
  {
    this.model = model;
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You've not actually added anything to the menus (other then exit)??

Comment: It is just an example. All menus have more than three entries.

Comment: So, how are you populating the menus then?

Comment: Same like the "menuItemExit" and then adding it to the menu, and after that adding it to the JMenuBar. The JMenuItems are all existing and the function is working correct, but no text on the Items.

Comment: Can we see the code for `ActionExit` or any of the other `Action` classes?

Comment: Added ActionExit class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JMenuItem` (and in fact all children of `AbstractButton`) derive their display text from the `Action.NAME` property.

Try something more like...

```
public class ActionExit extends AbstractAction
{
  private Model model;

  public ActionExit(Model model)
  {
    this.model = model;
    putValue(NAME, "Exit");
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Also, the `Action` class also defines the `mnemonic` and `accelerator` values.

Take a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and the [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) API for more details

Answer (score 1):

Check this one, my little lovely code, This program have just one **JMenuBar** in a **JFrame** and one **JMenuItem** in the **JMenuBar**, this might help you. All this program is do, exit the frame, when you click on the menuItem which is inside the menuBar :). To better understand, please run this program

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Class5 extends JFrame 
    {
        static JMenuBar exampleMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        static JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        static JMenuItem Exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");


public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        // construct frame
        new Class5().show();
    }
public Class5() 
   {
        // frame constructor
        setTitle("Menu Example");
        setSize(100, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // build menu
        setJMenuBar(exampleMenuBar);
        exampleMenuBar.add(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.add(Exit);

        Exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
            });



  }

}
```